# Why I can invoke "_objc_rootIsDeallocating" method?

Tags: ios

I define a method **_objc_rootIsDeallocating**. It can invoke system method when run the project. I wonder why it can invoke system method. The code likes in below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

bool _objc_rootIsDeallocating(id _Nonnull obj);

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    bool isDeallocating = _objc_rootIsDeallocating(self);
    NSLog(@"test is deallocating: %d", isDeallocating);
}

@end
```

Comment: `_objc_rootIsDeallocating` is `NSObject`'s private api https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm.auto.html . It makes sense that it needs to be available for objc-runtime and ARC as a resolved symbol by the means of linking.

Comment: So I define it just for Xcode compilation.When it invoked the system method will be invoked.@Kamil.S

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct. It "is" there, but the public header is not exposed by Apple, hence your local definition circumvents it. There's no guarantee the signature will match future objc runtime versions, so be careful. And if you invoke this function you will likely get rejected on Apple review if you provide such executable for their app review.